# Error deploying application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk with docker-compose and GitHub Actions

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a multi-container node.js application to Elastic Beanstalk. However, I am consistently getting the same error which is listed at the bottom of this question. My docker-compose for production looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
  client:
    image: anishsinha1/lifeofanish-client
    stdin_open: true

  api:
    image: anishsinha1/lifeofanish-server
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DATABASE=${POSTGRES_DATABASE}
      - POSTGRES_PORT=${POSTGRES_PORT}
      - POSTGRES_HOST=${POSTGRES_HOST}
      - SERVER_PORT=${SERVER_PORT}
  nginx:
    image: anishsinha1/lifeofanish-nginx
    depends_on:
      - api
      - client
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3050:80
```

and on my local machine, this works like a charm -- I can access my application on port 3050 and everything is persisted to a database. I have been setting up CI with GitHub Actions and my deploy.yml looks like this:

```
name: "Deploy to EBS"

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  prepare-env:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: SpicyPizza/create-envfile@v1.2
        with:
          envkey_POSTGRES_HOST: ${{ secrets.POSTGRES_HOST }}
          envkey_POSTGRES_PORT: ${{ secrets.POSTGRES_PORT}}
          envkey_POSTGRES_USER: ${{ secrets.POSTGRES_USER }}
          envkey_POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.POSTGRES_PASSWORD }}
          envkey_POSTGRES_DATABASE: ${{ secrets.POSTGRES_DATABASE }}
          directory: .
          file_name: .env.prod
  
  build-images:
    name: build docker images and deploy to ebs
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: docker login -u ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }} -p ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
      - run: docker build -t anishsinha1/lifeofanish-client:latest ./client 
      - run: docker build -t anishsinha1/lifeofanish-server:latest ./server
      - run: docker build -t anishsinha1/lifeofanish-nginx:latest ./nginx

      - name: generate deployment package
        run: zip -r deploy.zip *

      - name: Deploy final to elastic beanstalk
        uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v18
        with:
          aws_access_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws_secret_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_KEY }}
          application_name: lifeofanish
          environment_name: lifeofanish-env
          existing_bucket_name: elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-697480332228
          region: us-east-1
          version_label: ${{ github.sha }}
          deployment_package: deploy.zip
```

and everything seems to be working up till the actual deployment part. The messages I am getting are below. The error messages start at 08:06:26 and continue for about 7 lines.

```
Uploading file to bucket elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-697480332228
New build successfully uploaded to S3, bucket=elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-697480332228, key=/lifeofanish/00047d1686e776f4c661c47cdd4dd9ac9a4b02a8.zip
Created new application version 00047d1686e776f4c661c47cdd4dd9ac9a4b02a8 in Beanstalk.
Starting deployment of version 00047d1686e776f4c661c47cdd4dd9ac9a4b02a8 to environment lifeofanish-env
Deployment started, "wait_for_deployment" was true...

Request to DescribeEnvironments was throttled, that's 1 throttle errors in a row...
08:06:05 INFO: Environment update is starting.
08:06:10 INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).
08:06:26 ERROR: Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.
08:06:26 ERROR: Instance deployment failed to download the Docker image. The deployment failed.
08:06:30 ERROR: [Instance: i-0d8044f4c85ec7783] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..
08:06:30 INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
08:06:30 ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0d8044f4c85ec7783'. Aborting the operation.
08:06:30 ERROR: Failed to deploy application.
08:06:30 ERROR: During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.
08:06:36 ERROR: Deployment failed! Current State: Version: a8d57d93a6435f3fecca37bf8533bbe1a3ea809b, Health: Red, Health Status: Degraded
Error: Deployment failed: Error: Deployment failed! Current State: Version: a8d57d93a6435f3fecca37bf8533bbe1a3ea809b, Health: Red, Health Status: Degraded
```

with the important lines looking to be:

```
08:06:26 ERROR: Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.
08:06:26 ERROR: Instance deployment failed to download the Docker image. The deployment failed.
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, since my images seem to be building properly and running perfectly locally, are in DockerHub, and my actions file seems to be correct. Yet the error I'm getting seems to be that AWS cannot pull the image. If anyone could help me resolve this issue I'd be very grateful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This may not apply here, but what we have done in the past is to try to login to Amazon ECR first prior to anything related to Docker, with something like the following within GitHub actions (sorry for formatting):

      `- name: Login to Amazon ECR
        run: |
          aws ecr-public get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin public.ecr.aws
        env:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          AWS_REGION: us-east-1`

Comment: so did you find `eb-engine.log` file? What are the errors there?

Comment: @iurii_n Nothing of value. I read through it and I just got a golang error runtime stack and a message saying that aws failed to pull the image. I'm really at a loss